# In the CSS Grid layout, how does the sub-element be set to non-automatic scaling?

Tags: html, css, css-grid, grid-layout

```html
<div class="demo1">
  <p class="text1">Text1</p>
  <p class="text2">Text2</p>
  <p class="des">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ...</p>
</div>

<div class="demo2">
  <p class="text1">Text1</p>
  <p class="text2">Text2</p>
  <p class="des">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto modi fugiat odio impedit, ullam eveniet eos ea enim veritatis doloremque Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto modi fugiat odio impedit, ullam eveniet eos ea enim veritatis doloremque minima perferendis eius ipsa dicta inventore, optio vero cupiditate cum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto modi fugiat odio impedit, ullam eveniet eos ea enim veritatis doloremque minima perferendis eius ipsa dicta inventore, optio vero cupiditate cum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto modi fugiat odio impedit, ullam eveniet eos ea enim veritatis doloremque minima perferendis eius ipsa dicta inventore, optio vero cupiditate cum. minima perferendis eius ipsa dicta inventore, optio vero cupiditate cum.</p>
</div>
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.demo1,
.demo2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto);
}

.demo1 {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.demo1 .des {
  grid-area: 2/1/3/3;
}

.demo2 .des {
  grid-area: 1/1/3/2;
}
```

When i use css gird layout, i have some questions.

How to set `.text1` & `.text2` element width or height not auto scaling？

I want to their width or height equal content width or height.

Please help me，thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are asking how to set `.text1` & `.text2` so that the width and height are equal to its contents. Use `width: fit-content`

```css
.demo1,
.demo2 {
  width: fit-content;
}
```

Info about [fit-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/fit-content)
[Can I use `width: fit-content`?](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_width_fit-content) is showing 95% global support.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.demo1,
.demo2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto);
  width: fit-content;
}

.demo1 {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.demo1 .des {
  grid-area: 2/1/3/3;
}

.demo2 .des {
  grid-area: 1/1/3/2;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo1">
  <p class="text1">Text1</p>
  <p class="text2">Text2</p>
  <p class="des">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ...</p>
</div>

<div class="demo2">
  <p class="text1">Text1</p>
  <p class="text2">Text2</p>
  <p class="des">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto modi fugiat odio impedit, ullam eveniet eos ea enim veritatis doloremque Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto modi fugiat odio impedit, ullam eveniet eos ea enim veritatis doloremque minima perferendis eius ipsa dicta inventore, optio vero cupiditate cum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto modi fugiat odio impedit, ullam eveniet eos ea enim veritatis doloremque minima perferendis eius ipsa dicta inventore, optio vero cupiditate cum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto modi fugiat odio impedit, ullam eveniet eos ea enim veritatis doloremque minima perferendis eius ipsa dicta inventore, optio vero cupiditate cum. minima perferendis eius ipsa dicta inventore, optio vero cupiditate cum.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using `aspect-ratio`:

```css
.text1, .text2 {
  aspect-ratio: 1;
}

/* extra styles to highlight boxes*/
.text1 {background-color: #f7f7f7;}
.text2 {background-color: #e7e7e7;}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.demo1 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto);
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.demo1 .des {
  grid-area: 2/1/3/3;
  background-color: #d7d7d7;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo1">
  <p class="text1">Text1</p>
  <p class="text2">Text2</p>
  <p class="des">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: set `aspect-ratio` is useless, i want to set their width not auto scaling.